Exclusion of paths via Google RE2 flavour regex
I am trying to validate a string in Kubernetes CRD via pattern field, which should be a valid Unix path, which excludes several directories, such as /root, /boot, /dev etc.
The idea is to validate the following paths
Valid paths:

/
/home
/home/
/home/
/home/username/
/home/username
/var

Invalid paths:

home
home/username
home/username/
/root
/root/
root
root/
root/.config
/proc
/boot
/dev/

For validation I have composed the following regular expression:
^(?!/(proc|dev|sys|run|boot|root)\\b)(/[^/ ]*)+/?$

It works fine in Python with the following results:
/: True
/home: True
/home/: True
/home/: True
/home/username/: True
/home/username: True
/var: True
home: False
home/username: False
home/username/: False
/root: False
/root/: False
root: False
root/: False
root/.config: False
/proc: False
/boot: False
/dev/: False

However, in Kubernetes CRD pattern validation, a Google RE2 regex flavour is used, which does not support this style of negative lookahead and throws the following error:
Invalid value: "^(?!/(proc|dev|sys|run|boot|root)\\\\b)(/[^/ ]*)+/?$": must be a valid regular expression, but isn't: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

Is there any way I can convert the regular expression to this flavour? All help would be appreciated.

could you CAPTURE what you want and see if the capture group 1 is set like so: ^\/(?:[br]oot|proc|dev)|^(\/.*)? Else when it does come to MATCHING, you might need to INCLUDE rather than EXCLUDE if thats at all feasable

If you can write multiple patterns that all need to be valid, you could use this website to create a regex like this ^\/([^r\n]|r(r|o(r|or))*([^or\n]|o([^or\n]|o[^rt\n])))*(r(r|o(r|or))*(oo?)?)?$ for root and test, that all exclusions pass for a path to be valid.

or probably easiest - if possible - you could negate the validation (write an exclusion) all together? Then something like ^[^/\n].*$|^\/(?:(?:[br]oot|proc|dev).*)$ might work

This regex passes all your examples without using any look-arounds:
^/(var|home(/(username/?)?)?)?$

See live demo.
It creates a series of whitelisted paths by using nested optional suffixes.
